# CakePHP edit user gives validationErrror

Tags: php, cakephp

I am using CakePHP for my application, where I have a User model. This User has a password, which has a regex to validate. 
The regex forces the user to use a password at least 6 characters long, containing at least 1 number and special char.

The validation looks like this:

```
'password' => array(
     'ruleName' => array(
     'rule' => array('custom', '/^.*(?=.{6,})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[@#$%^&+=]).*$/i'),
            'message' => 'Password not legit',
            'allowEmpty' => true
     )
)
```

When I want to edit my password, this validation works great. But when I want to edit the user (no option to change password there), the $this->User->save() fails.

If I debug my $this->User->validationErrors, the only thing shown is:

```
array(
    'password' => '*****'
)
```

The password field is not set in my post data, so the validation should not happen at all.
When I comment this block of validation code, the user can be saved.

Anyone knows what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Do not include the password field on edit if you do not provide special handling for it. Tip: http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/08/25/working-with-passwords-in-cakephp/

Comment: @mark I didn't include the password on edit. Actually, I also added this piece of code in my controller to get it out of the post data if it is set: if (empty($this->request->data['User']['password'])) { unset($this->request->data['User']['password']); }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself already. Before saving the User object, I already did a $this->User->Read(null, $userid) for other purposes.

This resulted in remembering the values of the read (including password) in the $this->User object.

Since the save method is called on the $this->User object, the password value is trying to get saved too. But since ***** isn't valid according to the regex, the save fails.

Thanks for the help anyway!